# Execute WSF script with argument through Powershell

Tags: powershell, vbscript, wsh

I am trying to execute a WSF script file from a PowerShell command with an argument and can not get it to work.

The powershell script I am attempting to use that is failing is:

```
$rSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName server01
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { cscript "\\server1\filepath\script.wsf ARGUMEMT"  ; return $LastExitCode} -Session $rSession
Remove-PSSession $rSession
```

Now, if I run the PowerShell script above with out an argument the script executes as expected Also, if I just run the Cscript portion in cmd.exe with the argument it also works as expected.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong when trying to call the WSF file through powershell with the argument?

Thanks,

Phil

Comment: Have you tried using the call operator `&` ? `& cscript \\server1\filepath\script.wsf ARGUMENT`

Comment: Perhaps you should give us the error, or the argument. There may be something in your argument that needs to be escaped.